# dojo animation doesn't work for xPage panel

Tags: dojo, xpages

I want to wipeOut my panel. But it doesn't work for `<xp:panel>` component but does for `<div>`.
Here is my code:

```
<xp:panel id="myPanel">This is my panel</xp:panel>
.....
dojo.style("myPanel", "height", "");
dojo.style("myPanel", "display", "block");
var wipeArgs = {
        node: "myPanel"
    };
dojo.fx.wipeOut(wipeArgs).play();
```

This doesn't work either:

```
dojo.style("#{id:myPanel}", "height", "");
dojo.style("#{id:myPanel}", "display", "block");
var wipeArgs = {
        node: "#{id:myPanel}"
    };
dojo.fx.wipeOut(wipeArgs).play();
```

But this does work:

```
<div id="myDiv">This is my DIV</div>
.....
dojo.style("myDiv", "height", "");
dojo.style("myDiv", "display", "block");
var wipeArgs = {
        node: "myDiv"
    };
dojo.fx.wipeOut(wipeArgs).play();
```

So how do I make it work for xp:panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your Dojo code inside a `XSP.addOnLoad()` call in order for Dojo to use the id generated by XPages.

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
    XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
        dojo.style("#{id:myPanel}", "height", "");
        dojo.style("#{id:myPanel}", "display", "block");
        var wipeArgs = {
                node: "#{id:myPanel}"
            };
        dojo.fx.wipeOut(wipeArgs).play();
    });
]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Also, if you just want a div and not a div with a datasource attached to it, then you can use `xp:div` instead of `xp:panel`.

Comment: Well but where I add it to my button. I want to press a button and execute some SSJS code and then wipeOut my panel onComplete. If I just add this block to my panel it wipes out it on page load. Here is my button code:   
<xp:button value="Label" id="button3">
 <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh">
  <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:onClickSSfunction();}]]></xp:this.action>
  <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[alert("wipe out here!");]]></xp:this.onComplete>
 </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

Comment: OK.. solved this way:
var myPanelId = dojo.query("[id$=':myPanel']")[0].id;

dojo.style(myPanelId, "height", "");
dojo.style(myPanelId, "display", "block");
var wipeArgs = {
  node: myPanelId
 };
dojo.fx.wipeOut(wipeArgs).play();